# Proving $A \subset B \implies A \cup B = B$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove this:

$A \subset B \implies A \cup B = B$

One direction:

$x\in A \subset B$

$\implies x \in A \land x \in B$

$\implies x \in A \cup B$

$\implies x \in (A \cup B = B)$

Other direction:

$x \in (A \cup B = B)$

$\implies x \in A \land x \in B$  (I used $\land$ here instead of $\lor$ because it equals B, so it has to be in both sets.)

$\implies x \in A \subset B$

Is my proof correct or are there some steps missing.
If not I hope you could show me the right direction.

Comment: Your 'proof' seem to follow some formal rules and pattern in putting formulas one after the other, however it's just meaningless. How would, for example, $x$ be an element of the *equation* $(A\cup B=B)$? Also, the logical operation corresponding to union is 'or' instead of 'and'..

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$, assume $A\subseteq B$ and show that $A\cup B=B$. For $\Leftarrow$, assume $A\cup B=A$ and prove that $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse (1) expressions denoting sets ( such as A U B " A union B" , or A Inter B ) and (2) expressions expressing sentences ( such as " A in included / contained in B, or, A is equal to B). IF AN EXPRESSION EXPRESSES A SENTENCE, IT DOES NOT MAKE SENSE TO  USE A MEMBERSHIP SYMBOL IN FRONT OF IT. For example, I cannot write : " x belongs to  A is contained in B". So ONLY EXPRESSIONS DENOTING SETS CAN BE PRECEDED BY RELATION SYMBOLS such as  the membership symbol or the equality symbol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, but it's incorrect.

You want to show that “$A\subset B$” if and only if $A\cup B=B$”.

In order to do this, you have to prove

1. *If* $A\subset B$, then $A\cup B=B$
2. *If* $A\cup B=B$, then $A\subset B$

#### Proof of 1

Suppose $A\subset B$.

- Take $x\in A\cup B$; then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$; if $x\in A$, then, by assumption, $x\in B$. In either case, $x\in B$. Hence $A\cup B\subset B$
- Take $x\in B$; then $x\in A\cup B$. Hence $B\subset A\cup B$.

The two points above show that $A\cup B=B$.

#### Proof of 2

Suppose $A\cup B=B$. Take $x\in A$; then $x\in A\cup B$, so $x\in B$. Therefore $A\subset B$.

Comment: @egregThanks for your answer. I did a new proof below. My proof of 2 seems correct. Is my Proof of 1 below correct?

Comment: @franz3 neither is correct, sorry

Comment: @egregbut proof 2 is the exact same as yours. I did a new answer down below. I'm just not too sure about the first part of my proof

Comment: @franz3 No, it isn’t. Your idea may be right, but a proof is not just a sequence of symbols that merely suggest your idea.

Answer (score 6):

What you should have done for the proofs:

Proof of 1
Suppose $A\subset B.$

Take $x\in A\cup B.$ Then we have two possibilities: $x\in A$ or $x\in B.$ If $x\in A,$ $x\in B$ by assumption, and the case when $x\in B$ immediately holds. So $A\cup B\subset B.$ If $x\in B,$ then $x\in A\cup B,$ and so $B \subset A\cup B.$  Thus $A\cup B=B.$

Proof of 2
Suppose $A\cup B=B.$
Let $x\in A$. Then $x\in A\cup B.$ By hypothesis, $x\in B.$ Thus $A\subset B.$

Answer (score 2):

($\implies$) Suppose that $ A\subseteq B $.

Take any $ x\in A \cup B $, so $ x\in A $ or $ x\in B $. Since $ A\subseteq B $ and $ x\in A $, so $ x\in B $. Then, we have $ A\cup B \subseteq B $.

Take any $ x\in B $. Since $ A\subseteq B $ and $x\in B$, so $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. Then, we have $B\subseteq A\cup B$.

Since $ A\cup B \subseteq B $ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$, so $A\cup B=B$.

($\impliedby$) Suppose that $A\cup B= B$.

Take any $ x\in A\cup B $, so $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, in particular, $x\in A$. Since $A\cup B=B$ and $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in B$.

Since for any $x\in A \implies x\in B$, then we have $A\subseteq B$

Answer (score 1):

Below a proof using the natural deduction method.

The goal is read as a simple implication : if A is included in B , then ... ( not as a double implication). [image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I hope this is better.

Let $x \in A \subset B$.

$\Rightarrow x \in A \land x \in B \Rightarrow x \in (A \cup B) \Rightarrow x \in B \Rightarrow x \in (A \cup B = B)$.

Assume $A \cup B = B$.

Let $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in (A \cup B) \Rightarrow x \in B \Rightarrow x \in (A \subset B)$.

Could you please show me any mistakes or ways to improve it.

Comment: Besides egreg's very valid point that simply stringing symbols together in a sequence does not make a valid argument, both of your "proofs" contain "$x \in (A\cup B) \implies x \in B$", which is not true (in these cases it is true that $x \in B$, but for other reasons than this). You also include the statements $x \in (A\cup B = B)$ and $x \in (A \subset B)$ which had already been pointed out to you as being non-sensical. They makes as much sense as saying $1 + 1 = \text { a goose}$.

Comment: This proof is wrong. Note that all the other answers here don't shy away from using *words* to explain their reasoning when necessary, so there's really no reason for you to intentionally avoid words either. It's clearly only confusing you.