# Use $A \cup B = B \cap C$ to show that $A \subset B \subset C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three sets. Using the property $$A \cup B = B \cap C$$ of these sets I have to show that $$A \subset B \subset C$$ What I have done until now is to use $$A \cup B \Rightarrow B \cap C$$ with the formal definitions (1) $A \cup B = x \in A \lor x \in B$, (2) $B \cap C = x \in B \land x \in C$ and (3) $p \Rightarrow q = \lnot p \lor q$ to do the following:
$$(x \in A \lor x \in B) \Rightarrow (x \in B \land x \in C)$$
$$\lnot(x \in A \lor x \in B) \lor (x \in B \land x \in C)$$
$$(\lnot(x \in A) \land \lnot(x \in B)) \lor (x \in B \land x \in C)$$
$$((\lnot(x \in A) \land \lnot(x \in B)) \lor x \in B) \land ((\lnot(x \in A) \land \lnot(x \in B)) \lor x \in C)$$
$$((\lnot(x \in A) \lor x \in B) \land (\lnot(x \in B) \lor x \in B) \land (\lnot(x \in A) \lor x \in C) \land (\lnot(x \in B) \lor x \in C)$$
Using the same definitions (1), (2) and (3) as before this yields
$$(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B) \land (x \in B \Rightarrow x \in B) \land (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in C) \land (x \in B \Rightarrow x \in C)$$
with the definition for subset $A \subset B = x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ we finally get
$$(A \subset B) \land (B \subset B) \land (A \subset C) \land (B \subset C)$$
Which in my opinion is already what we want since we find that A is a subset of $B$ and $C$ and $B$ is a subset of $C$. However, I am not really sure if this was the right way or is even correct. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: $A∪B ⇒ B∩C$ is wrong; the hypothesis is $A∪B = B∩C$

Comment: The proof must be: if $x \in A$ then $x \in A \cup B$. By hypothesis this implies $x \in B \cap C$ that means: $x \in B$ and $x \in C$.

Comment: What @MauroALLEGRANZA said, you should indeed use that fact and not short it. So if $x\in A\cup B = B\cap C$ then $x\in A \lor x\in B$ and $x\in B\wedge x\in C$. Then it just goes by cases from here.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A\cup B\implies B\cap C$"? The expression $A\cup B$ is not a statement (i.e., it does not have a *truth value*), so it cannot be used in a logical formula.

Comment: For the first part, the initial assumption implies that every element in $A\cup B$ is an element of $B$, because every element of $B\cap C$ is an element of $B$. This shows that $A\subset B$ because $A\subset A\cup B$. The second part uses similar reasoning.

Comment: In correct set notation, $A \cup B = \{x : x \in A \lor x \in B\}.$ Is someone encouraging you to omit the brackets and the "$x :$"?

Comment: Thank you very much @MauroALLEGRANZA and Gaurav Chandan and sorry for the bad notation I just started to study math and this how the lecturers introduced the notation (although I previously knew the full set notation I guess I was just lazy here). So if I understood correctly the new reasoning would be:
$A \subset B \Rightarrow (A \cup B) = B$. Assuming this is true we can then do $B = B \cap C$ which in turn implies $B \subset C$. Thus, if $A \subset B$ and $B \subset C$ we can also write $A \subset C$. Would this make sense?

Comment: "the new reasoning would be: $A⊂B ⇒ (A∪B)=B$. Assuming this is true..." NO; we have to prove $A⊂B$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I tried to find a proof but I think I am really stuck here. I found this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3410652/602358 and it seems this would proof $(A \cup B) = B$ using the assumptions $A \subset B$ but still this does not proof $A \subset B$.

Comment: In the linked answer there are two parts. The first part is "proof of 1" and does not match what you need. The second part is "proof of 2" and it is (almost) exactly what you need in order to show that $A \subset B$.

Comment: Okay so one last try for today:
Suppose (1) $(A \cup B) = B$. If $x \in A$, then by definition of the union we get (2) $x \in (A \cup B)$. Since we assume (1) with (2) we immediately get $x \in B$. Which is equivalent to (3) $A \subset B$. Now again taking $x \in (A \cup B)$ we either have $x \in A \lor x \in B$ but since (3), we get that if $x \in A$ then also $x \in B$ and thus in either of these cases $x \in B$ which shows that $(A \cup B) = B$. Finally we can write $B = B \cap C$ which can only be true if $B \subset C$. Thus $A \subset B \land B \subset C \iff A \subset B \subset C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'll attempt to elaborate on my comment above and show you a full proof, but since you (the OP) are getting pretty close to the proof yourself, I'll hide it in spoilers, so you can just verify your answer when you get one.

> We have, 1) $A\cup B = B\cap C$
>
> Using the definition of intersections, we can conclude that: 2) $\forall x[x\in B\cap C \implies x\in B]$

> But 1) says that $B\cap C = A\cup B$. Substituting this equality in 2) we get: 3) $\forall x[x\in A\cup B \implies x\in B]$ and since, by the definition of union, $\forall x[x\in B \implies x\in A\cup B]$ we can conclude that: 4) $A\cup B = B$

> Now, using the definition of a union again, $A\subset A\cup B = B$ Therefore, $A\subset B$

This completes the first part of the required proof.

For the next part,

> We have 5) $A\cup B = B\cap C$ Substituting equality 4) in 5), we get, 6) $B = B\cap C$

> Then, using the definition of intersections, we find that $\forall x[x\in B\cap C \implies x\in C$]. Substituting equality 6) here, we get $\forall x[x\in B \implies x\in C$], which is very nearly the exact logical translation of $B\subset C$

This completes your proof.

And yes, $[A\subset B]\land[B\subset C]\implies A\subset B\subset C$

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. So all that was missing was to proof that $A \cup B = B$. Glad, I got at least the second part right. I would upvote but I do not have enough reputation yet. Nevertheless, thanks for the help

Comment: Don't worry about it @mnmldani